# Anyway to Override [TestCleanup] for a single [TestMethod]?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium

So I have a [TestClass] with some [TestMethods] implemented and I have a [TestCleanup] performing the verification of all but a single method, causing that one method to fail. Is there any way to override that TestCleanup for this single method?

I *could* get rid of the TestCleanup & perform the individual verifications within each tests, but I'd like to not do that if I can, to avoid redundant code.

Comment: There is no way to "override" it for a single method but provided that you run your tests sequentially, you could set a class-level flag field in the test method and evaulate the flag in the cleanup method.